# Open URL by h:selectOneMenu

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, seam

I have a JSF1.2 selectOneMenu component.
Currently, a user selects an item from the dropdown menu, then clicks an output link to open a url in a new browser window:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{itemSelected}"  valueChangeListener="#{someclass.generateInfoForURL}" onchange="submit()" >
  <s:selectItems var="_items" value="#{itemsList}" label="#_items.itemName}" /> 
  <s:convertEntity />
</h:selectOneMenu>  

<h:outputLink value="URL&amp;generatedInfo=#{someclass.component.generatedInfo}" target="_blank" > 
    <f:verbatim>View Report</f:verbatim>            
</h:outputLink>
```

What I need is; when a user selects one of the dropdown items it should open the URL in a new page without the intermediate step of selecting the link.  I can build the URL in the backing bean, but how do I get it to open a new browser window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the URL as item value and use JavaScript to open it in a new tab/window instead of to submit the form. You only need to ensure that all URLs are already rightly prepared beforehand.

E.g.

```
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="window.open(value)">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select page.." />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="page1" itemValue="page1.jsf" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="page2" itemValue="page2.jsf" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="page3" itemValue="page3.jsf" />
    ...
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

*(you can of course supply it as `<f/s:selectItems>`, the above is just a basic kickoff example)*

Comment: I tried: `<h:selectOneMenu value="#{someclass.itemSelected}"  onchange="window.location = http://'#{ourHostName}'/report_war/preview?__report=reportNmae.rptdesign&amp;rpt_id=
  '#{someclass.generateInfoForURL()}'">
  <s:selectItems var="_items" value="#{itemsList}" label="#_items.itemName}" /> 
  <s:convertEntity />
</h:selectOneMenu>`   The page loads but the generateInfoForURL method runs on page load and thats it, selecting an item from the dropdown does nothing.  Did I miss something?

Comment: Your JS syntax is invalid. The quotes should go around the JS string, not around EL expressions. Easier is to just let item value return the right value already. EL expressions are namely not re-evaluated when you change the value. Now I see better what you're trying to achieve, you might want to perform the redirect in the value change listener method instead. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: thanx BalusC, that works, but doesn't open a new page, it redirects the current page.  I'm giving it a one cuz I will need this elsewhere and I'll mark it as the answer if I can't work out the JS to open a new page.

Comment: Oh sorry I completely missed that part. Your best bet is then JavaScript's `window.open(url)` method. Make sure that the URLs are prepared right beforehand and then do it in the `onchange`.